# Camel Spring Java Failing To parse accented characters

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a file containing records that are delimited by accented characters ý example below

```
janeýdoe
```

I am trying to read these records using a camel route below (minimalistic)

```
from("/data/names.txt?noop=true&charset=UTF-8")
  .idempotentConsumer(header(CAMEL_FILE_NAME),                                                
    FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(new File(
      baseInputPath + "/tracker/" + fileType + "files.txt")))
  .log("Body: ${body}").end();
```

The route is failing to parse the data with the accented character, the output is coming out below

```
Body: jane∩┐╜doe
```

How do I make sure the accented character is parsed correctly so that I can use it to split the data?

I am using the Camel spring boot starter version 4.3.0